# How to display string inline?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to force in twitter bootstrap show text inline with `overflow`? For example in http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/jJdX4/ `overflow` is working except the inline words. In my code nothing works.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `white-space` and set it to `nowrap` which will make text go into one line until a break is reached.

```
li {white-space:nowrap;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jJdX4/1/